# How to write an expression using sigma notations?

Tags: summation

If I have $4^{n-1}*6+4^{n-2}*6+4^{n-3}*6+...+4*6 + 6$ how do I rewrite such expression as sum notation? I do know the answer, I don't really understand how to go from this expression and make a sigma notation?

Comment: How about $6\times \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}4^i$?

Comment: As I said, I know the answer, but I do not understand how to get there so I am asking more for an explanation rather than a plain answer

Comment: Not sure what to tell you.  Factor out the $6$.  What's left is $(1+4+4^2+\dots +4^{n-1})$ which is literally $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}4^i$, standard Geometric Series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have terms of the form $4^i\times 6$, where $i$ starts from $n-1$ and finishes at $0$. In notation, $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} 4^i\times 6,$$
or, equivalently, $6 \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}4^i$.

Comment: Can we rewrite this as $6(4^n-1)$?

Comment: No, the sum evaluates to $6\times \tfrac13(4^n-1)$.

Comment: Do you use sum of geometric sequence to figure that out?

Comment: Yes, the sum is $\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}=\frac{1-4^n}{1-4}$.